# I want to Obtain Twitter Follower and Following List in android But getting NullPointer

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

i want to obtain twitter follower user list that why i am using following code but giving NullPointer on   `for (User user : followers)` and see this link http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-examples/2.2.4/twitter4j/examples/list/GetAllUserLists.java here they guided to how to get Users in Java  but `ResponseList<UserList> lists = twitter.getAllUserLists(args[0]);` in this link what is arg[0] as per method  http://twitter4j.org/ja/javadoc/twitter4j/api/ListMethods.html please guide me to solve my problem.

```
 private static final String user ="your-user";
 private static final String pw ="your-password";


    // Make a Twitter object
           Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(user,pw);

    // Set my status
    twitter.setStatus("@vogella messing with Twitter in Java");

    List<User> followers = twitter.getFollowers();
    for (User user : followers) {
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: through this i am able to get All POst https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth  but i want Follower and following list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my knowledge, Twiiter has updated their apis, now they are supporting oauth 2.0  mechanism to retrieve any info.

To retrieve followers lis you should use below link
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids
you can use Twitter4j library for java/android
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

```
private void twitter_req()
{

        String access_token = prefs.getString("twitter_token", null);
        String access_secret = prefs.getString("twitter_secret", null);

              twitter_api lapi=new twitter_api(access_token,access_secret,new GetUserInfo_TWRequestCallback());
                lapi.get("api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json ");

}
public void get() {
        try {
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(mUrl);
                sign(httpRequest);
                sendSync(httpRequest);
        } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d(" get()", e.toString());
                doFailCallback();
        }
}
private void sendSync(HttpRequestBase httpRequest)
{

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            //

            //
            response = "null";
            if (entity != null) {
                response = getResponseFromStream(entity.getContent());  //
            }
}
public void sign(HttpRequestBase httpRequest) throws OAuthMessageSignerException, OAuthExpectationFailedException {
       // MSOAuth oauth = MSOAuth.init(mSession);
       // oauth.sign(httpRequest);
         try {
        consumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            response="errorsign";
            if(e!=null)
                if(e.getMessage()!=null)
                {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
}
```

Comment: dude tried but i want follower list through this i am able to get All POst https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth but i want Follower and following list

Comment: you have to use http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json instead of http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json in the class where it is getting all post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the API but it doesn't seem clear if the returned list can be null or not according to javadoc. Check if it is before looping.

Comment: cousin, it's not a very good idea to call the statement if( a!= null ) { //loop } some code, as it might not be a good idea to call people brother in international english